# Update JavaScript variable on a HTML Select value change

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to update a variable in javascript when the value of a HTML select value changes.

When I choose option 2 or 3 in the browser, the level variable still displays option 1 value (level = 2).

If it's not possible I would love to hear some other alternatives.

**Here's the HTML -->**

```
<select id="nivel">
        <option value="1">easy</option>
        <option value="2">medium</option>
        <option value="3">hard</option>
</select>
<p id="lvl">Level: </p>
```

**Here's the js-->**

```
var level;
if(document.getElementById("nivel").value == "1"){
        level = 2;
    }
      else{
        if(document.getElementById("nivel").value == "2"){
            level = 5;
        }else{
            level = 9;
        }
      }
 document.getElementById("lvl").innerHTML=("Level: " +level);
```

Comment: You are not handling any _change_ here, this code only reads the currently selected value _once_. Are you familiar with the basics of JavaScript event handling? If not, that is something you need to go read up on first.

Comment: please re-visit the question, i made a small mistake, now corrected

Comment: Still no sign of event handling going on _anywhere_.

Comment: `function setLevel() { document.getElementById("lvl").innerHTML=("Level: " +[2,5,9][this.selectedIndex]); }
var nivel= document.querySelector("#nivel");
nivel.onchange=setLevel;
nivel.onchange();` http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/L1dhwfut/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

1. You need to associate a `change` event in the `select` dropdown
2. You are using incorrect `id` in the `if` condition. It should be `nivel` and not `lvl`
3. Call `changeLevel()` function on page load so that it will set the default `level` variable based on the default selection.

```js
function changeLevel(){
  var level;
  if(document.getElementById("nivel").value == "1"){
      level = 2;
  }
  else{
    if(document.getElementById("nivel").value == "2"){
        level = 5;
    } else{
        level = 9;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("lvl").innerHTML=("Level: " +level);
}
changeLevel();
```

```html
<select id="nivel" onchange='changeLevel()'>
        <option value="1">easy</option>
        <option value="2">medium</option>
        <option value="3">hard</option>
</select>
<p id="lvl">Level: </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to map values with levels using HTML5 `data-` attribute:

Option 1: With JS

```js
var nivel = document.getElementById('nivel');
var lvl = document.getElementById('lvl');
nivel.onchange = function() {
  lvl.innerHTML = 'Level: ' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-level');
};
nivel.onchange();
```

```html
<select id="nivel">
  <option value="1" data-level="2">easy</option>
  <option value="2" data-level="5">medium</option>
  <option value="3" data-level="9">hard</option>
</select>
<p id="lvl"></p>
```

Option 2: With jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $('#nivel').on('change', function() {
    $('#lvl').text('Level: ' + $(this).find('option:selected').data('level'));
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="nivel">
  <option value="1" data-level="2">easy</option>
  <option value="2" data-level="5">medium</option>
  <option value="3" data-level="9">hard</option>
</select>
<p id="lvl"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some alter with ? : -> replacing if.. else
Check this snippet, i hope it will help

```js
var level;
function updateLevel(event) {
  level = event.value;
  level = (level && level == '1') ? '2' : (level == '2') ? '5' : (level > 2) ? '9':''; 
  document.getElementById("lvl").innerHTML = ("Level: " + level);
}
```

```html
<select id="nivel" onchange="updateLevel(this)">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">easy</option>
  <option value="2">medium</option>
  <option value="3">hard</option>
</select>
<p id="lvl">Level: </p>
```

Comment: Different values for 1,2,3

Comment: @mplungjan thats the requirement, show 2 if selected 1, show 5 if selected 2, show 9 if selected 3.